# How do i create a table in a mysql database when i dont have 'create' permission from my host?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin, hosting

So basically i have signed up to several free hosts who provide a free SQL database for testing. 
But the problem is the the user_id they create for these free databases never seems to have 'CREATE' permission.

I am using PHP and PDO to connect to the database and i need to programmatically create a table with PDO.

How do i get 'CREATE' permission for my user_id or create a new user who has the required permission?

I use phpmyadmin to connect to these databases manually.

EDIT: Kindly note that i can create tables with PHPMyAdmin but not through PDO. When i use PDO, server tells me i don't have CREATE permssion

Comment: If the host doesn't provide `CREATE TABLE` permission, then you can't `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I cannot believe this. What should be then the reason for the database you got?

Comment: I can add tables with phpmyadmin but not through PDO apparently

Answer (score 0):

If you can create tables through PHPMyAdmin and not through your own PHP script then it might be because PHPMyAdmin is using different MySQL user.
In your PHPMyAdmin goto "SQL" button on top and enter this query:

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

It will show you the logged in user in PHPMyAdmin, try using this user in your PHP script.

If you don't wish to use the same user. Then in the SQL query execute this:

```
GRANT ALTER, CREATE ON your_db_name TO 'your_php_user'@'localhost';
```

This will give the CREATE and ALTER TABLE permission to your user.

Comment: You are right. When i type 'SELECT CURRENT_USER()' it displays a different username. But when i type the grant query using 'SQL' tab, it says 'grant command denied to <original username>.

Comment: Based on your report here, it seems your host is doing something odd to restrict or limit your access. You should ask your hosting provider's support team for assistance with this matter; it seems there is nothing we can do to change their infrastructure.